# scope.$eval() returning old value

Tags: validation, angularjs, scope, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I've got a form with two date values. I want to validate: **date one must be lower than date two**. I want to do a directive to manage this. So, I named my directive **lowerThanDate** and I'm using it into a text input. This directive uses two date attributes: **date** and **comparisonDate**. I want to compare this values to know if date is lower than comparison date or not.

I'm using **scope.$eval** to get those date values and compare them. But, the problem is that **scope.$eval** is returning the previous values not the actual values.

So, the question is: **How can I get the actual date values?**

This is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/O4e7olMaaPw2HcSpxvxK) with my issue. Sorry if my question is dumb, I'm pretty new in Angular. Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angularjs [input directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3ainput) automatically updates the property data-bound to the input by the `ng-model` property.  As the value in the textbox changes, so does the bound property.

Additionally, the `datepicker-popup` directive from the ui-bootstrap library is already handling the date selection event to update the data-bound property (in this case, `job.start_date`).  This means that you don't have to bind to the `focusout` event of the element; the datepicker directive is taking care of this.

Since you're requiring the `ngModel` controller in your custom directive and the `datepicker-popup` is already applying the update to the data-bound property when the selected date changes, you can just `$watch` the value of `ngModel.$modelValue` for changes.  This also means the `Date` attribute can be completely eliminated.

With all this in mind, the body of your directive's `link` function becomes:

```
scope.$watch(function(){return ngModel.$modelValue}, function(){
    console.log(ngModel.$modelValue);
    console.log(scope.$eval(attrs.comparsionDate));
});
```

Here's the [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FGCIibCyNZppfvHqdYPq?p=info).

I also went a step further and fully implemented the lowerThanDate functionality leveraging the angularjs [form validation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) capabilities.  When the selected date is not lower than the comparison date, the `$error` property of `ngModel` can be set by the directive, and used in the HTML to display a message/keep the form from being submitted.

Here's [the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IZdGpIMOxabFxTWz8fYZ), and here's [a blog post](http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/form-validation-the-angularjs-way) about form validation that I found useful.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick. What you want to do is to bind the date inputs to values using the ng-model attribute. Your directive (validator in my example) will have an isolate scope. The date:'=' sets up a bi-directional binding between the local value (date) and the parent scope value (dateInput). In the link function, you can assign dateValidation to the directive's scope, which will do the comparison between the dates.

Lastly, an ng-show='dateValidation(date, comparisonDate)' shows and hides the warning based on whether the dateValidation function passes.

Also, note that comparisonDate is spelled differently in the HTML.

```
angular.module('YourApp')
    .directive('validator', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: "<div ng-show='dateValidation(date, comparisonDate)'>Dates are out of order</div>",
            scope: {
                date:'=',
                comparisonDate:'='
            },
            link: function(scope) {
                scope.dateValidation = function(date, comparisonDate) {
                    // Your date comparison logic goes here
                    return parseInt(date) > parseInt(comparisonDate);
                };
            }
        }
    });
```

In your HTML, you want to attach the dates to an ng-model attribute, as follows:

```
<p>Date 1: <input type="text" ng-model="dateInput"></p>
<p>Date 2: <input type="text" ng-model="comparisonDateInput"></p>

<validator date="dateInput" comparison-date="comparisonDateInput">
```

Okay, so I'm treating these dates as integers, which is not exactly what you want. However, it doesn't sound that like that's the sticking point for you. Hope this helps!